# Using JUnit @BeforeClass with Cucumber...does it work?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber

Currently my driver is set at the @Before method -

```
@Before("@setup") public void setUp() {
        driver = utilities.DriverFactory.createDriver(browserType);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

And is called from the Feature file like so -

```
@test
Feature: Test 

  @setup
  Scenario: Navigate to Webpage and Assert Page Title
```

My understanding is that the driver gets set every time there is a scenario, which is not ideal. It should only be set one time. Is it possible to use the JUnit `@BeforeClass` (It doesn't seem Cucumber has one) so that I can set it only once? Do those two libraries mix together?

Answer (score 0):

You can use junit `BeforeClass` to create the driver. As this is a static method,the driver variable has to be static too. Also `AfterClass` can be used to close the driver.